# The ways to construct columns associated with interaction terms in data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 6 columns,

```
dat<-data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6)
```

Right now, I need to build two extra columns associated with interaction terms, `x1*x2` and `x3*x4*x5` How to do that in R. Are there any special consideration when some of them, such as `x2` is categorical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the function `model.matrix` does exactly what you want.

For instance, you can fit a linear model including the variables and interaction terms you're interested in and then extract the model matrix from that fitted object

```
model.matrix(lm(drat ~ mpg * cyl + disp * hp * wt, data = mtcars))
```

Factors need to be explicitly coded as factors, find an example below

```
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl)
model.matrix(lm(drat ~ mpg * cyl + disp * hp * wt, data = mtcars))
```

The default kind of contrasts used for factors is treatment coding. You can easily change this to sum coding (or other codings: `?contr.sum`) by using the command below

```
contrasts(mtcars$cyl) <- contr.sum
```